# Assets in Flutter package are not visible in the app

Tags: flutter, dart, package, assets

I've created a package, which uses some assets (sf2 file, ttf files, etc). Assets don't seem to load. I can fix this by including these files in the assets folder of my main project (so now, every asset in the package is also in my main project). However, when I build a web app, it still creates an extra folder for my package with the files that it needs.

Is there a way around this? How do I enforce the package to use the assets from itself?

Comment: I'm also building a flutter package with an example app in it. This package also has some widgets that I'm using in the example app. This widgets can't see the assets.

Answer (score 4):

After some digging, I've found a way to include it.

`'packages/livescore_sdk/assets/default_team_logo.png'` works instead of `'assets/default_team_logo.png'`

Comment: yeah. this is exactly what you should be doing as assets are placed inside that pacakge.

Comment: I will test this today. I still have some trouble with having duplicate assets folders though :/

Comment: Why do you have that issue? I'm keeping my assets in the package, reaching them the way I described above. I'm not duplicating any folders for that setup

Answer (score 0):

Include the assets in your lib folder, and import it from local project only.

Assuming the project name `ABC`:

###### Steps

1. Create assets folder in lib, example: `lib/assets`. Full assets example url: `ABC/lib/assets/some_asset.png`
2. Copy the assets in this folder.
3. Import the assets in your pubspec.yaml like this:

```yaml
  assets:
    - packages/ABC/assets/some_asset.png
```

Hope this help someone.  :smiley:

Comment: thanks for the input but how this is different than my answer? any benefits of using lib/assets folder instead of the assets folder?

Comment: "Anything in the lib/ folder will get automatically bundled with the app. Those assets will be available to anyone who uses your package. As the package developer, you don’t even need to declare those assets in pubspec.yaml if you are not using them yourself. They’ll still be bundled with the package".[reference](https://medium.com/flutter-community/including-assets-in-a-flutter-package-dd4a82a38ca9). If you are creating a package for the use of others,in lib/assets will be accessible, in external assets don't

Answer (score 0):

To make assets in a Flutter package visible in your app, you need to follow a few steps:

1. Create an assets folder inside the lib directory of your package. This is where you will store your assets.
2. In your package's pubspec.yaml file, specify the assets you want to include. Add the following code under the flutter section:

> flutter:   assets:
> - packages/[YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME]/assets/[ASSET_NAME.EXT]

Replace [YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME] with the actual name of your package, and [ASSET_NAME.EXT] with the name and extension of your asset file.

3. To use the asset in a widget, you can use the Image.asset() constructor. Specify the path to the asset relative to the package's assets folder and provide the package name using the package parameter. Here's an example:

> Image.asset('assets/[ASSET_NAME.EXT]', package: 'YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME')

Make sure you have properly followed these steps and that the assets are correctly located in your package's assets folder. Also, ensure that you have run flutter pub get or flutter packages get to update your app's dependencies.